# Substitution command in neovim remaps not working

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, substitute

I simply want to map < leader> pu to erase all occurrences of the carriage return character (represented as ^M) in a file.

I can execute the command:

```
:%s/\r//g
```

and it works.

Any attempts to use vim.keymap.set in my remap.lua file, however, error out when I try to source it.

Attempts include:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd('%s/\r//g'))
```

Errors with "Pattern not found:" using square brackets errors with "Pattern not found:\r"

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd.substitute{ range = '%', args = {'\r',''} })
```

Errors with " Invalid command arg: expected non-whitespace"

An attempt with a different character, 'r', sources, but applies the command inside the sourced file instead of mapping it.

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd('%s/r//g'))
```

I have other mappings using vim.cmd that work fine, and do not apply in the remap file.

Maybe this is a skill issue, but I need some assistance.

Comment: See `:help file-formats`. Would `:set fileformat=unix` solve your problem? This will only affect CRLF line endings while your regexp will also erase CR characters not at the end of a line. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Due to the file formats, when pasting into nvim on WSL from system clipboard, <CR>s are at the end of each line. Just tried changing the file format, but they still appear (using both dos and unix). I just don't understand why I cannot map this replace, as typing it in manually every time I paste something in is getting tiresome.

Comment: You should ask about how not to get CRLF line endings when pasting in the first place. Being forced to run a mapping whenever you paste something is not a solution.

Comment: I slapped paste from clipboard in there too, so no additional keystrokes are required. When I asked the question I did not know about file formats; this works for me where the other responses dealing with file formats do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<leader>pu', ':%s/\\r//<CR>', {})
```

Comment: For the record, I think the issue is that vim.cmd is evaluated when constructing the mapping (since Lua is expression-oriented and has no macros, the expression can only be delayed with a function wrapper or, in this particular case, using a string)

Answer (score 1):

why not write it directly in unix format?

```
:w ++ff=unix
```